# Foul water sump needs a gentle tap to start

Tags: electrical, sump

I have a foul water sump in my basement and it no longer automatically starts after the water in its chamber rises and the float switch floating. It’s is not the float switch fault as this was checked. The body of the pump needs a gentle tap with a stick and it immediately starts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to disassemble the pump to find out the cause. Here are *some* possibilities:

- A [centrifugal switch](https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Electric-Motor-Centriugal-Switch-PRD-PTC.php) *inside* the motor is dirty or sticking.

  Clean the switch contacts or replace the switch.
- There is too much friction on the motor shaft or pump impeller for it to spin until shaking breaks the ["stiction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction), static friction.

  Clean the impeller and the motor; lubricate the motor.
- An electrical connection to the motor or switch has loosened.

  Check all connections; tighten or replace connectors as needed.
- The float is not able to push up the switch.

  Clean the float and switch assembly; check if the float is water-logged; lubricate, if the manual suggests that (perhaps paraffin wax rubbed on moving parts).